# Manipulating color of SVG in template node

Tags: svg, node-red

Using Raspberry PI and node-red template node, I want to modify color of many SVG groups in a single SVG created from inkscape.

As I am new to SVG manipulation in real time, for starters, I began experimenting with a available code snippets and node-red. I am using below code in a template node in node-red. When I send fill-color string as a message to the template node, I expect fill color of the circle to be update. But, it stays black.

Need help to fix the situation

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Live (websocket)</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ws;
    var wsUri = "ws:";
    var loc = window.location;
    console.log(loc);
    if (loc.protocol === "https:") { wsUri = "wss:"; }
    // This needs to point to the web socket in the Node-RED flow
    // ... in this case it's ws/simple
    wsUri += "//" + loc.host + 
 loc.pathname.replace("simple","ws/simple");

    function wsConnect() {
        console.log("connect",wsUri);
        ws = new WebSocket(wsUri);
        //var line = "";    // either uncomment this for a building list of messages
        ws.onmessage = function(msg) {
            var line = "";  // or uncomment this to overwrite the existing message
            // parse the incoming message as a JSON object
            var data = msg.data;
            //console.log(data);
            // build the output from the topic and payload parts of the object
            line += "<p>"+data+"</p>";
            // replace the messages div with the new "line"
            document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = line;
            //ws.send(JSON.stringify({data:data}));
        }
        ws.onopen = function() {
            // update the status div with the connection status
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "connected";
            //ws.send("Open for data");
            console.log("connected");
        }
        ws.onclose = function() {
            // update the status div with the connection status
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "not connected";
            // in case of lost connection tries to reconnect every 3 secs
            setTimeout(wsConnect,3000);
        }
    }

    function doit(m) {
        if (ws) { ws.send(m); }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="wsConnect();" onunload="ws.disconnect();">
    <font face="Arial">
    <h1>Realtime control display</h1>
    <div id="messages"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick='doit("on");'>On</button>
    <hr/>
    <button type="button" onclick='doit("off");'>Off</button>
    <hr/>
    <div id="status">unknown</div>
    </font>
    <svg height="100" width="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="{{msg.payload}}" />
    </svg>
</body>
```

The flow:

```
[{"id":"b42c1d77.a106","type":"tab","label":"Flow 4","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"26b9acf6.07d0f4","type":"inject","z":"b42c1d77.a106","name":"Tick every 5 secs","topic":"test","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"1","crontab":"","once":false,"x":270,"y":540,"wires":[["30c6a524.97098a"]]},{"id":"9a2dd892.72c338","type":"websocket out","z":"b42c1d77.a106","name":"","server":"c74fd37a.71a1a","client":"","x":760,"y":540,"wires":[]},{"id":"43b92be3.166a34","type":"http response","z":"b42c1d77.a106","name":"","statusCode":"","headers":{},"x":910,"y":280,"wires":[]},{"id":"6a79a785.0d46d8","type":"http in","z":"b42c1d77.a106","name":"","url":"/simple","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":270,"y":160,"wires":[["e79b8060.3bbdb"]]},{"id":"29d9680c.f456a8","type":"template","z":"b42c1d77.a106","name":"Simple Web Page","field":"payload","fieldType":"msg","format":"javascript","syntax":"mustache","template":"<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html>\n    <head>\n    <title>Live (websocket)</title>\n    <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n        var ws;\n        var wsUri = \"ws:\";\n        var loc = window.location;\n        console.log(loc);\n        if (loc.protocol === \"https:\") { wsUri = \"wss:\"; }\n        // This needs to point to the web socket in the Node-RED flow\n        // ... in this case it's ws/simple\n        wsUri += \"//\" + loc.host + loc.pathname.replace(\"simple\",\"ws/simple\");\n\n        function wsConnect() {\n            console.log(\"connect\",wsUri);\n            ws = new WebSocket(wsUri);\n            //var line = \"\";    // either uncomment this for a building list of messages\n            ws.onmessage = function(msg) {\n                var line = \"\";  // or uncomment this to overwrite the existing message\n                // parse the incoming message as a JSON object\n                var data = msg.data;\n                //console.log(data);\n                // build the output from the topic and payload parts of the object\n                line += \"<p>\"+data+\"</p>\";\n                // replace the messages div with the new \"line\"\n                document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = line;\n                //ws.send(JSON.stringify({data:data}));\n            }\n            ws.onopen = function() {\n                // update the status div with the connection status\n                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = \"connected\";\n                //ws.send(\"Open for data\");\n                console.log(\"connected\");\n            }\n            ws.onclose = function() {\n                // update the status div with the connection status\n                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = \"not connected\";\n                // in case of lost connection tries to reconnect every 3 secs\n                setTimeout(wsConnect,3000);\n            }\n        }\n        \n        function doit(m) {\n            if (ws) { ws.send(m); }\n        }\n    </script>\n    </head>\n    <body onload=\"wsConnect();\" onunload=\"ws.disconnect();\">\n        <font face=\"Arial\">\n        <h1>Realtime control display</h1>\n        <div id=\"messages\"></div>\n        <button type=\"button\" onclick='doit(\"on\");'>On</button>\n        <hr/>\n\t\t<button type=\"button\" onclick='doit(\"off\");'>Off</button>\n        <hr/>\n        <div id=\"status\">unknown</div>\n        </font>\n        <svg height=\"100\" width=\"100\">\n        <circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"40\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"3\" fill=\"{{msg.payload}}\" />\n        </svg>\n</body>\n</html>\n\n\n","x":710,"y":280,"wires":[["43b92be3.166a34"]]},{"id":"30c6a524.97098a","type":"function","z":"b42c1d77.a106","name":"format time nicely","func":"msg.payload = Date(msg.payload).toString();\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":530,"y":540,"wires":[["9a2dd892.72c338"]]},{"id":"6900903b.9c411","type":"websocket in","z":"b42c1d77.a106","name":"","server":"c74fd37a.71a1a","client":"","x":280,"y":400,"wires":[["e79b8060.3bbdb","3c0453f0.6d3a4c","2e506fd.e6a219"]]},{"id":"e79b8060.3bbdb","type":"debug","z":"b42c1d77.a106","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"complete":"false","x":510,"y":220,"wires":[]},{"id":"dc0f2d44.3e53","type":"rpi-gpio out","z":"b42c1d77.a106","name":"","pin":"15","set":"","level":"0","freq":"","out":"out","x":760,"y":400,"wires":[]},{"id":"3c0453f0.6d3a4c","type":"change","z":"b42c1d77.a106","name":"","rules":[{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"on","fromt":"str","to":"0","tot":"num"},{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"off","fromt":"str","to":"1","tot":"str"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":512,"y":402,"wires":[["dc0f2d44.3e53"]]},{"id":"723486cc.880e98","type":"inject","z":"b42c1d77.a106","name":"","topic":"","payload":"0","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":"","x":510,"y":480,"wires":[["dc0f2d44.3e53"]]},{"id":"2e506fd.e6a219","type":"change","z":"b42c1d77.a106","name":"","rules":[{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"on","fromt":"str","to":"lime","tot":"num"},{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"off","fromt":"str","to":"red","tot":"str"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":520,"y":340,"wires":[["29d9680c.f456a8"]]},{"id":"c74fd37a.71a1a","type":"websocket-listener","z":"b42c1d77.a106","path":"/ws/simple","wholemsg":"false"}]
```

Thank you for suggestion, I have updated my username.

Quick update: Reason I want to use websocket is to be able to do session login control for admin and multiple users. Not sure if this flow is the best approach. I tried copying this idea [websocket + node-red](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/node-red/JSHYvAOOFIs/sElqNYhWCAAJ). But, cannot figure out how to place server side scripts in the flow.

I also tried SVG manipulation directly by using ui_template node. But again, changing color of individual group elements; independently, remains a question :(

Got a good direction from hardillb

Updated the node as below to have first meaningful connection between http and websocket nodes.

```
[{"id":"7bef62d0.5edcfc","type":"tab","label":"Flow 1","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"9de3d2d9.d89de","type":"websocket out","z":"7bef62d0.5edcfc","name":"","server":"1a7afc32.b3ad64","client":"","x":800,"y":260,"wires":[]},{"id":"2944ff33.7e483","type":"http response","z":"7bef62d0.5edcfc","name":"","statusCode":"","headers":{},"x":810,"y":180,"wires":[]},{"id":"4333a9ac.bae3b8","type":"http in","z":"7bef62d0.5edcfc","name":"","url":"/simple","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":270,"y":180,"wires":[["708c64d.fce949c"]]},{"id":"708c64d.fce949c","type":"template","z":"7bef62d0.5edcfc","name":"Simple Web Page","field":"payload","fieldType":"msg","format":"javascript","syntax":"mustache","template":"<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html>\n    <head>\n    <title>Live (websocket)</title>\n    <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n        var ws;\n        var wsUri = \"ws:\";\n        var loc = window.location;\n        console.log(loc);\n        if (loc.protocol === \"https:\") { wsUri = \"wss:\"; }\n        // This needs to point to the web socket in the Node-RED flow\n        // ... in this case it's ws/simple\n        wsUri += \"//\" + loc.host + loc.pathname.replace(\"simple\",\"ws/simple\");\n\n        function wsConnect() {\n            console.log(\"connect\",wsUri);\n            ws = new WebSocket(wsUri);\n            //var line = \"\";    // either uncomment this for a building list of messages\n            ws.onmessage = function(msg) {\n                var line = \"\";  // or uncomment this to overwrite the existing message\n                // parse the incoming message as a JSON object\n                var data = msg.data;\n                //console.log(data);\n                // build the output from the topic and payload parts of the object\n                line += \"<p>\"+data+\"</p>\";\n                // replace the messages div with the new \"line\"\n                document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = line;\n                document.getElementById('circle').setAttribute('fill',data)\n                //ws.send(JSON.stringify({data:data}));\n            }\n            ws.onopen = function() {\n                // update the status div with the connection status\n                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = \"connected\";\n                //ws.send(\"Open for data\");\n                console.log(\"connected\");\n            }\n            ws.onclose = function() {\n                // update the status div with the connection status\n                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = \"not connected\";\n                // in case of lost connection tries to reconnect every 3 secs\n                setTimeout(wsConnect,3000);\n            }\n        }\n        \n        function doit(m) {\n            if (ws) { ws.send(m); }\n        }\n    </script>\n    </head>\n    <body onload=\"wsConnect();\" onunload=\"ws.disconnect();\">\n        <font face=\"Arial\">\n        <h1>Realtime control display</h1>\n        <div id=\"messages\"></div>\n        <button type=\"button\" onclick='doit(\"on\");'>On</button>\n        <hr/>\n\t\t<button type=\"button\" onclick='doit(\"off\");'>Off</button>\n        <hr/>\n        <div id=\"status\">unknown</div>\n        </font>\n        <svg height=\"100\" width=\"100\">\n        <circle id=\"circle\" cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"40\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"3\" fill=\"{{msg.payload}}\" />\n        </svg>\n</body>\n</html>\n\n\n","x":570,"y":180,"wires":[["2944ff33.7e483"]]},{"id":"ca3dab00.a83708","type":"websocket in","z":"7bef62d0.5edcfc","name":"","server":"1a7afc32.b3ad64","client":"","x":320,"y":260,"wires":[["988c505.812f3b"]]},{"id":"988c505.812f3b","type":"change","z":"7bef62d0.5edcfc","name":"","rules":[{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"on","fromt":"str","to":"green","tot":"str"},{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"off","fromt":"str","to":"red","tot":"str"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":560,"y":260,"wires":[["9de3d2d9.d89de"]]},{"id":"1a7afc32.b3ad64","type":"websocket-listener","z":"7bef62d0.5edcfc","path":"/ws/simple","wholemsg":"false"}]
```

However relying on my first principles approach, I still do not have any idea about how to connect dots between admin/user session login, websockets and mongoDB all via node red.

Any pointers in this direction are very welcome...

Comment: Update the question with a copy of your flow so we can see how you've wired things up. (As an aside choosing NodeRed as a username is probably not the best, it implies you have something to do with the project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, to start with you have no path from your http-in node to your http-response node so you will never return anything to the browser.

The following flow does what I think you are looking to do, it changes the colour of the circle every second based on toggling a value (stored in the context) each time the inject node fires.

```
[{"id":"24197499.be00c4","type":"inject","z":"5be0b71a.38c42","name":"Tick every 1 second","topic":"test","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"1","crontab":"","once":false,"x":280,"y":340,"wires":[["e1102298.1909f8"]]},{"id":"b4c3d38c.82c0d","type":"websocket out","z":"5be0b71a.38c42","name":"","server":"2a3ae677.f9c272","client":"","x":760,"y":340,"wires":[]},{"id":"dc2352e9.bdfdd","type":"http response","z":"5be0b71a.38c42","name":"","statusCode":"","headers":{},"x":810,"y":160,"wires":[]},{"id":"5f7966e5.03b278","type":"http in","z":"5be0b71a.38c42","name":"","url":"/simple","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":270,"y":160,"wires":[["cef934de.0ad83"]]},{"id":"cef934de.0ad83","type":"template","z":"5be0b71a.38c42","name":"Simple Web Page","field":"payload","fieldType":"msg","format":"javascript","syntax":"mustache","template":"<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html>\n    <head>\n    <title>Live (websocket)</title>\n    <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n        var ws;\n        var wsUri = \"ws:\";\n        var loc = window.location;\n        console.log(loc);\n        if (loc.protocol === \"https:\") { wsUri = \"wss:\"; }\n        // This needs to point to the web socket in the Node-RED flow\n        // ... in this case it's ws/simple\n        wsUri += \"//\" + loc.host + loc.pathname.replace(\"simple\",\"ws/simple\");\n\n        function wsConnect() {\n            console.log(\"connect\",wsUri);\n            ws = new WebSocket(wsUri);\n            //var line = \"\";    // either uncomment this for a building list of messages\n            ws.onmessage = function(msg) {\n                var line = \"\";  // or uncomment this to overwrite the existing message\n                // parse the incoming message as a JSON object\n                var data = msg.data;\n                //console.log(data);\n                // build the output from the topic and payload parts of the object\n                line += \"<p>\"+data+\"</p>\";\n                // replace the messages div with the new \"line\"\n                document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = line;\n                document.getElementById('circle').setAttribute('fill',data)\n                //ws.send(JSON.stringify({data:data}));\n            }\n            ws.onopen = function() {\n                // update the status div with the connection status\n                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = \"connected\";\n                //ws.send(\"Open for data\");\n                console.log(\"connected\");\n            }\n            ws.onclose = function() {\n                // update the status div with the connection status\n                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = \"not connected\";\n                // in case of lost connection tries to reconnect every 3 secs\n                setTimeout(wsConnect,3000);\n            }\n        }\n        \n        function doit(m) {\n            if (ws) { ws.send(m); }\n        }\n    </script>\n    </head>\n    <body onload=\"wsConnect();\" onunload=\"ws.disconnect();\">\n        <font face=\"Arial\">\n        <h1>Realtime control display</h1>\n        <div id=\"messages\"></div>\n        <button type=\"button\" onclick='doit(\"on\");'>On</button>\n        <hr/>\n\t\t<button type=\"button\" onclick='doit(\"off\");'>Off</button>\n        <hr/>\n        <div id=\"status\">unknown</div>\n        </font>\n        <svg height=\"100\" width=\"100\">\n        <circle id=\"circle\" cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"40\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"3\" fill=\"{{msg.payload}}\" />\n        </svg>\n</body>\n</html>\n\n\n","x":570,"y":160,"wires":[["dc2352e9.bdfdd"]]},{"id":"e1102298.1909f8","type":"function","z":"5be0b71a.38c42","name":"format time nicely","func":"if (context.get('state') == 'on') {\n    context.set('state', 'off')\n    msg.payload = 'green'\n} else {\n    context.set('state', 'on')\n    msg.payload = 'red';\n}\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":530,"y":340,"wires":[["b4c3d38c.82c0d"]]},{"id":"2a3ae677.f9c272","type":"websocket-listener","z":"5be0b71a.38c42","path":"/ws/simple","wholemsg":"false"}]
```

If you just want to change the colour of the circle without using your own websocket connection then the Dashboard-UI ui-template node is the way forward, but you will have to learn some basic angular to get that to work. There are plenty of examples around to help with that.

Comment: Thank you so much for being so kind. It has been less than 24 hours on Stack Overflow and I am already supported by a person of repute.